# Will graphql run resolver with additional arguments

Tags: graphql, apollo

If graphql query schema is like this:

```
user(user_id: Int): User
```

Will apollo run resolver if in query will be additional (email) argument not defined in query schema?

I want iterate arguments in resolver, but not sure if it possible to pollute them.

P.S. If there is documentation of how apollo parcing arguments, will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GraphQL, a schema defines what fields are available to the client, including what arguments are available for that field and what the types of those arguments are. Any query submitted to a GraphQL service will first be validated before it's executed. If the query includes any extraneous arguments, it will fail validation and won't be executed. This is explained [here](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Argument-Names) in the spec:

> Formal Specification
>
> - For each argument in the document
> - Let argumentName be the Name of argument.
> - Let argumentDefinition be the argument definition provided by the parent field or definition named argumentName.
> - argumentDefinition must exist.
>
> Explanatory Text
>
> Every argument provided to a field or directive must be defined in the set of possible arguments of that field or directive.

For a better idea of how GraphQL works, I would suggest taking at least a cursory look through the spec.